# any way to identify a specific app via iOS keychain access group prefix?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, keychain

I'm peeking in the keychain-2.db of my jailbroken iPhone and finding a lot of items with just the access group prefix and a wildcard (eg. "0123456789.*"). Is there a way to find which app/developer is linked to the 10-characters prefix just by looking at some plist files or somewhere else, **not** programmatically?

Comment: Does compiling and running [this](http://github.com/ptoomey3/Keychain-Dumper) count as "not programmatically"?

Comment: I know, but it's only showing the content of the keychain, which I already see. I do not need to recover passwords, but to understand who is the owner of a specific item. I suspect many of "1234567890.*" are tracking user privacy in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe there is a way to know what developer is associated with the keychain prefix.  Last time I looked it was the App ID prefix, which is either the team ID of the developer or randomly generated (and I don't believe there to be a public index of either of these things).

Comment: So the only way would be comparing the keychain on a "test phone" before and after app first installation?

Comment: Well, you still wouldn't be able to tell who the developer was based on the ID.  It would also depend on when the app uses the keychain.  It may or may not initialize it on first launch (it might not touch it until you login, or some such, for example).